# In pytorch, how to debug the JIT error information "RuntimeError: Only tensors or tuples of tensors can be output from traced functions"?

Tags: python-3.x, pytorch, jit

I wrote a simple pytorch Sequential module for which I plan to convert to ONNX for visualisation & mobile deployment. The first step is to convert it into JIT version:

```
        input = torch.rand(1, 3, 300, 300, dtype=torch.float32, device=device)
        mod = FPNImproved(raw)
        torch.jit.trace(mod, input)
```

This step gave me the following error:

```
        for method_name, example_inputs in inputs.items():
            # this is needed since Module.__call__ sets up some extra tracing
            func = mod if method_name == "forward" else getattr(mod, method_name)
            example_inputs = make_tuple(example_inputs)
>           module._c._create_method_from_trace(method_name, func, example_inputs, var_lookup_fn, _force_outplace)
E           RuntimeError: Only tensors or tuples of tensors can be output from traced functions (getOutput at /opt/conda/conda-bld/pytorch_1570711556059/work/torch/csrc/jit/tracer.cpp:209)
E           frame #0: c10::Error::Error(c10::SourceLocation, std::string const&) + 0x47 (0x7f35dca71687 in /home/shared/conda3/envs/cv-torch/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/lib/libc10.so)
E           frame #1: torch::jit::tracer::TracingState::getOutput(c10::IValue const&) + 0x365 (0x7f35aa607105 in /home/shared/conda3/envs/cv-torch/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/lib/libtorch.so)
E           frame #2: torch::jit::tracer::exit(std::vector<c10::IValue, std::allocator<c10::IValue> > const&) + 0x3c (0x7f35aa60740c in /home/shared/conda3/envs/cv-torch/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/lib/libtorch.so)
E           frame #3: <unknown function> + 0x57472a (0x7f35e62fd72a in /home/shared/conda3/envs/cv-torch/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/lib/libtorch_python.so)
E           frame #4: <unknown function> + 0x58bbb4 (0x7f35e6314bb4 in /home/shared/conda3/envs/cv-torch/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/lib/libtorch_python.so)
E           frame #5: <unknown function> + 0x206506 (0x7f35e5f8f506 in /home/shared/conda3/envs/cv-torch/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/lib/libtorch_python.so)
E           frame #6: _PyMethodDef_RawFastCallKeywords + 0x254 (0x56498498e744 in /home/shared/conda3/envs/cv-torch/bin/python)
E           frame #7: _PyCFunction_FastCallKeywords + 0x21 (0x56498498e861 in /home/shared/conda3/envs/cv-torch/bin/python)
E           frame #8: _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 0x52f8 (0x5649849fa6e8 in /home/shared/conda3/envs/cv-torch/bin/python)
E           frame #9: _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName + 0x2f9 (0x56498493e539 in /home/shared/conda3/envs/cv-torch/bin/python)
E           frame #10: _PyFunction_FastCallKeywords + 0x325 (0x56498498def5 in /home/shared/conda3/envs/cv-torch/bin/python)
E           frame #11: _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 0x416 (0x5649849f5806 in /home/shared/conda3/envs/cv-torch/bin/python)
E           frame #12: _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName + 0x2f9 (0x56498493e539 in /home/shared/conda3/envs/cv-torch/bin/python)
E           frame #13: _PyFunction_FastCallKeywords + 0x325 (0x56498498def5 in /home/shared/conda3/envs/cv-torch/bin/python)
E           frame #14: _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 0x4b39 (0x5649849f9f29 in /home/shared/conda3/envs/cv-torch/bin/python)
E           frame #15: _PyFunction_FastCallKeywords + 0xfb (0x56498498dccb in /home/shared/conda3/envs/cv-torch/bin/python)
E           frame #16: _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 0x416 (0x5649849f5806 in /home/shared/conda3/envs/cv-torch/bin/python)
E           frame #17: _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName + 0x2f9 (0x56498493e539 in /home/shared/conda3/envs/cv-torch/bin/python)
E           frame #18: _PyFunction_FastCallDict + 0x400 (0x56498493f860 in /home/shared/conda3/envs/cv-torch/bin/python)
E           frame #19: _PyObject_Call_Prepend + 0x63 (0x56498495de53 in /home/shared/conda3/envs/cv-torch/bin/python)
E           frame #20: PyObject_Call + 0x6e (0x564984950dbe in /home/shared/conda3/envs/cv-torch/bin/python)
E           frame #21: _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 0x1e42 (0x5649849f7232 in /home/shared/conda3/envs/cv-torch/bin/python)
E           frame #22: _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName + 0x2f9 (0x56498493e539 in /home/shared/conda3/envs/cv-torch/bin/python)
E           frame #23: _PyFunction_FastCallDict + 0x400 (0x56498493f860 in /home/shared/conda3/envs/cv-torch/bin/python)
E           frame #24: _PyObject_Call_Prepend + 0x63 (0x56498495de53 in /home/shared/conda3/envs/cv-torch/bin/python)
E           frame #25: <unknown function> + 0x16ba3a (0x564984995a3a in /home/shared/conda3/envs/cv-torch/bin/python)
E           frame #26: _PyObject_FastCallKeywords + 0x49b (0x5649849968fb in /home/shared/conda3/envs/cv-torch/bin/python)
E           frame #27: _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 0x569f (0x5649849faa8f in /home/shared/conda3/envs/cv-torch/bin/python)
E           frame #28: _PyFunction_FastCallKeywords + 0xfb (0x56498498dccb in /home/shared/conda3/envs/cv-torch/bin/python)
E           frame #29: _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 0x6a3 (0x5649849f5a93 in /home/shared/conda3/envs/cv-torch/bin/python)
E           frame #30: _PyFunction_FastCallDict + 0x10b (0x56498493f56b in /home/shared/conda3/envs/cv-torch/bin/python)
E           frame #31: _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 0x1e42 (0x5649849f7232 in /home/shared/conda3/envs/cv-torch/bin/python)
E           frame #32: _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName + 0xac9 (0x56498493ed09 in /home/shared/conda3/envs/cv-torch/bin/python)
E           frame #33: _PyFunction_FastCallKeywords + 0x387 (0x56498498df57 in /home/shared/conda3/envs/cv-torch/bin/python)
```

Unfortunately this message doesn't help, as I'm under the impression that all the layers in my modules already have tensors or tuples output. Even worse the error message doesn't tell me which layer is the culprit.

What is the recommended way to ask pytorch JIT to explain it? I already enabled PYTORCH_JIT=0.

I'm using pytorch 1.3.0 with only CPU support

Comment: HI! I'm not really sure if it is still relevant to you but I've got kind of the same issue. On of my methods returns a list of strings. So generally speaking if your method returns something other then NUMBERS it's not allowed.